# Displaying Localized Vocabulary on Skin-based Folder Listing

Tags: plone

I understand it's better to [write browser view in a product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346850/custom-view-for-displaying-contents-in-folder), but want to know if there's any quick solution to the following task.

I have a custom Dexterity type with a `cities` field:

```
cities = schema.List(
  title=_(u"Cities"),
  value_type=schema.Choice(
    vocabulary='cities',
    required=False,
  ),
)
```

Values in the **vocabularies.py** look like:

```
SimpleTerm(value="NewYorkCity", title=_(u"New York City")),
```

Now I want utilize Skin-based template **folder_listing.pt** and add the following to display the `cities` values.

```
<tal:cities condition="item_obj/cities"
          tal:repeat="city item_obj/cities">
  <span tal:replace="city">Value</span>
  <span class="separator" tal:condition="not:repeat/city/end">,</span>
</tal:cities>
```

It displays the results as NewYorkCity, but I really want is its translated title in Chinese, like 紐約市. If feasible, how can I meet this needs with template customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to use i18n:domain and i18n:translate :

```
<span i18n:domain="yourdomain" i18n:translate="" tal:replace="city">Value</span>
```

(see http://wiki.zope.org/zope3/ZPTInternationalizationSupport)

Comment: Additional details for the record: Manually add vocabulary values into POT file, use i18ndude to sync them into PO file.